# I am unable to fetch json data from wp_db

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to fetch data from wp_table.But query is show blank.If I am trying to get integer value then output is come .Like if I am  try to fetch data integer type like user_id then query show output .but trying to fetch varchar data its showing null. For example I want fetch product data from my table data is in json "[{\"product\":\"MY PRODUC5\"},{\"product\":\"PRODUCT 2\"}]". and my sql query is .

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM diary_user_form_storage");
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
  $productString = stripslashes($value->product);
    echo $p1=json_decode($productString,true);
}
```

If data is not in json array form then out put is coming .But all data is in this form `[{\"product\":\"MY PRODUC5\"},{\"product\":\"PRODUCT 2\"}]`

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question. The problem is on query not on `json_decode` right?

Comment: Also please share the `var_dump` output of `$value->product`

Comment: Laxmana@I have done this . I am doing this with implode . after json_decode I am using implode function

Comment: downvoted as basically this is a php question. in addition it is better to strip slashes before writing to the values to the DB, not when reading it.

Comment: Mark Kaplun@i tried to stripe slashes before inserting data in databse but that time I was not able to solve this

Answer (score -1):

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM diary_user_form_storage");
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
  $productString = stripslashes($value->product);
   $product=json_decode($productString,true);
  $error_p = implode(' ', $product[0]);
echo  $error_p;


}
```

Out will be PRODUCT 2 PRODUCT 5